# Losing precision when converting from inches to centimeter and vice versa

Tags: java, double, precision

I am actually loosing precision values when I convert from `Inches to Centimeter` and Again `Centimeter to Inches`.

// Inches to Centimeter

```
public static String convertInchesToCentimeter(String inches) {
    double in = 0;
    try {
        if (inches != null && inches.trim().length() != 0) { in = Double.parseDouble(inches) / 0.39370;
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfx) {
        System.err.println("Invalid input.");
    }
    return String.valueOf( in );
}
```

// Centimeter to Inches

```
public static double convertCentiToInch(double d) {
    double centiToInch = 0;
    if (String.valueOf(d) != null && String.valueOf(d).trim().length() != 0) {

        centiToInch = d * 0.39;
    }
    return centiToInch;
}
```

If i enter `45, its showing 44.58`. I don't know where the is the exact problem happening?

Comment: What's with the `String.valueOf(d) != null`? That will **never** return `null`. And checking the `length` of the result is equally pointless!

Comment: Please use `BigDecimal` if you can't life with such errors in your numbers. Also don't use shortened numbers like `0.39` but use `1/25.4`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have 0.39370 in one function and 0.39 in the other.

The *exact* number is 1 inch is 2.54cm.

Comment: Incredible that such a question leads to a post in So

Comment: Another pair of eyes I guess: I've just fixed a bug in some of my code which was an error far worse than that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem is that you are using `0.39370` in one function, but `.39` in the other. I'd recommend using the exact value of `2.54` centimeters per inch.

Even with this change, floating point numbers are often imprecise.